# Data Attribute Not Showing

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, custom-data-attribute

I have a featured image that is displaying in Wordpress. I've added a data-attribute to the image like the following...

```
 <img  src="<?php echo $large_image ?>" 
       data-img="<?php echo $large_image ?>" 
       data-title="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" 
       data-description="<?php the_content();?>" 
       alt="" class="superbox-img" />
```

I'd like to display data-title and data-description on the front end of the website but its not showing up for some reason. I'm a big noob when it comes to data-attributes so I do apologize for the beginner aspect. I don't know if I should show the title and description through CSS `content: attr(data-title)` or through jquery.

Comment: Note, that it's safer if you use [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on you data attribute values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get data attributes values with jquery: http://api.jquery.com/data/

```
<section data-role="page" data-page-num="42" data-hidden="true">
    <!-- Imagine a bunch of page-type content here... -->
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log($('section').data('role'));
    // Expect string "page"

    console.log($('section').data('pageNum');
    // Expect 42, an integer...! 

    console.log($('section').data('hidden');
    // Expect the boolean TRUE!
</script>
```

Comment: I'll try this and take a look at the jquery api link.

Comment: Okay this is working I'm seeing the title in the console. Need to figure out how to echo it now. Thank you!

Comment: I have 

<script>
          jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
           console.log($('img.superbox-img').data('title'));
          });
         </script>

Is it possible to display it now on the web page? That may be a stupid question.

Comment: yes you can include the complete script in your php file, or in separated js file

Comment: Right, but I have no idea how to display it on the page and not in console. Would something like this work? <script>
          jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
           $(this).html('h3' + $('img.superbox-img').data('title') + '</h3>');
           
          });
         </script>

Comment: assuming you have an h3 in your html like : `<h3 class="yourClass"></h3>` you can set his text like that :
$("h3").text( $('img.superbox-img').data('title'));

http://docs.jquery.com/Text()

Comment: I'm really just trying to put it into this in the class="superbox-show" div. -> http://pastie.org/7117506

Answer (score -1):

The data attribute is used to "create" your own set of html attributes. In your example, you have created 3 more attributes called data-img, data-title, data-description.

It's up to your application how you access these properties so you can access them using Jquery or even apply CSS rules!